# Поиск строк в Traducir

Tags: поддержка, локализация, traducir

Как найти нужную строку в Traducir? Например, нашел на сайте неправильный перевод в профиле, вместо "проверки" отображается "проверок":

[image: reviews]

Но в Traducir при поиске "reviews" находится только строка 74dcb1cec50854d2f880279f3dd19da9 (reviews -> рецензии).

Comment: Я бы предположил, что так https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMeW5.png, но результат пустой. И по `^\s*проверок\s*$` тоже ничего.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Примечание переводчика: текст автора находится внизу сообщения; перевод же выполнен другим человеком, не имеющим к автору отношения. Просьба оставлять комментарии на английском языке.*

Спасибо, что сообщили об этом!

В апреле 2018 года я создал ru.traducir.win. Для этого я:

- вытащил строки из Transifex,
- импортировал переводы из базы данных Stack Overflow.

На тот момент запуск ещё не состоялся, но сайт уже был настроен. Вчера я импортировал переводы из базы данных Stack Overflow.

Этот импорт не перетёр то, что уже было в базе данных. Вот почему в Traducir остались старые строки (которые не совпадают с тем, что было в базе данных SO и, следовательно, на сайте).

Благодаря вашему отчету я сделал импорт базы данных SO, убедившись, что строки перезаписаны, и теперь вы можете видеть, что [строка в Traducir соответствует тому, что показано на сайте](https://ru.traducir.win/string/4556). Я убедился, что ни одна строка не имела статус одобренной, так что я не отменил никаких действий рецензентов.

---

Thanks for reporting it!

In April 2018, I set up ru.traducir.win. As part of that:

- I pulled the strings from Transifex
- I imported the translations from the Stack Overflow database

We didn't launch it at that time, but the site was already set up. Yesterday, I imported the translations from the Stack Overflow database.

That import didn't override what was already on the database... and that's how I had old strings in Traducir (that don't match what was on the SO database, and therefore, on the site).

Thanks to your report, I did an import of the SO database making sure strings are overwritten and now you can see that [the string on Traducir matches what's shown on the site](https://ru.traducir.win/string/4556). I verified that no strings were approved, so I didn't roll back any actions taken by reviewers here.